# Modifying PS2/RPROMPT on Zsh/Powerlevel10K

Tags: zsh

I have Zsh and Powerlevel10k installed on my machine (no Oh My Zsh). I'm attempting to customize the terminal. However, when I type in a command with unclosed quotes, my prompt gets odd.

```
~ ❯ echo "Hello
user@machine ~ dquote>
user@machine ~ dquote> "
Hello
```

I'm attempting to have the terminal just say `'~ dquote>'`. Judging by the results I get when I run `echo $PS2`, I assume that's what I have to change.

```
%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{cyan}%(4~|...|)%3~%F{white} %_> %b%f%k
```

I attempted to set PS2 to `'~ dquote>'` (either on `~./zshrc` or `~/.p10k.zsh`), but with no success.

Comment: What do you mean by .zsrc? The file does not have a specific meaning to zsh. It should be .zshrc. However, you are using p10k, and I could imagine that this overwrites your PS2 settings.

Comment: You're right, it's .zshrc and I've edited it for clarity. As for p10k, its documentation explicitly states they did not change PS2.

Comment: So, you can verify that the PS2 is changed (`echo $PS2`), and still the secondary prompt has not changed?

Comment: ~ ❯ echo $PS2
%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{cyan}%(4~|...|)%3~%F{white} %_> %b%f%k

~ ❯ echo "Hello
user@machine ~ dquote> "
Hello

~ ❯ echo "Hello" |
user@machine ~ pipe> cat
Hello
~ ❯



So basically, PS2 is set as "%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{cyan}%(4~|...|)%3~%F{white} %_> %b%f%k" (not on "env", though), and I cannot see where on .zshrc or .p10k.zsh that definition is happening.

Comment: It does not make sense to put such multiline information into a comment. You find next to your question a tiny edit button, which you can use add additional findings to your question.

Comment: *Something* changed `PS2`, because the default value is just `%_>`, not all the stuff you are seeing. You can put `PS2="%_>"` in your `.zshrc`, but you need to ensure it's after whatever gets executed for Powerlevel10K, or it will overwrite your local changes. If you type `PS2="%_>"` at your command line and the change *still* doesn't persist, somethign is messing with a pre-command hook and resetting the value of `PS2` before every prompt.